# how can I exclude some data based on another data

Tags: awk, sed

I have two data, 1.txt and 2.txt, I am trying to remove those that are in 1.txt from the 2.txt

1.txt is

```
P13674
Q7Z4N8
O14683
Q9UHX1
```

and 2.txt is the following

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
VECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDIIIVLDQKDHAVFTRRGEDLFMCMDIQLVEALCGFQKPISTLDNRTIVITSHPGQIVKHGDIKCVLNEGMPIYRRPYEKGRLIIEFKVNFPENGFLSPDKLSLLEKLLPERKEVEE
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWVTQIATTPQFPDMILSASRDKTIIMWKLTRDETNYGIPQRALRGHSHFVSDVVISSDGQFALSGSWDGTLRLWDLTTGTTTRRFVGHTKDVLSVAFSSDNRQIVSGSRDKTIKLWNTLGVCKYTVQDESHSEWVSCVRFSPNSSNPIIVSCGWDKLVKVWNLANCKLK
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
IQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQL
>sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
MQPILLLLAFLLLPRADAGEIIGGHEAKPHSRPYMAYLMIWDQKSLKRCGGFLIRDDFVLTAAHCWGSSINVTLGAHNIKEQEPTQQFIPVKRPIPHPAYNPKNFSNDIMLLQLERKAKRTRAVQPLRLPSNKAQVKPGQTCSVAGWGQTAPLGKHSHTLQEVKMTVQEDRKCES
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
MGKDYYQTLGLARGASDEEIKRAYRRQALRYHPDKNKEPGAEEKFKEIAEAYDVLSDPRKREIFDRYGEEGLKGSGPSGGSGGGANGTSFSYTFHGDPHAMFAEFFGGRNPFDTFFGQRNGEEGMDIDDPFSGFPMGMGGFTNVNFGRSRSAQEPARKKQDPPVTHDLRVSLEEIYSGCTKKMKISHK
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
IVVKGHSTCLSEGALSPDGTVLATASHDGYVKFWQIYIEGQDEPRCLHEWKPHDGRPLSCLLFCDNHKKQDPDVPFWRFLITGADQNRELKMWCTVSWTCLQTIRFSPDIFSSVSVPPSLKVCLDLSAEYLILSDVQRKVLYVMELLQNQEEGHACFSSISEFLLTHPVLSFGIQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQLNPDVVAPLPTHTAHEDFTFGESRPELGSEGLGSAAHGSQPDLRRIVELPAPADFLSLSSETKPKLMTPDAFMTPSASLQQITASPSSSSSGSSSSSSSSSSSLTAVSAMSSTSAVDPSLTRPPEELTLSPKLQLDGSLTMSSSGSLQASPRGLLPGLLPAPADKLTPKGPGQVPTATSALSLELQEVEP
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
MIHNYMEHLERTKLHQLSGSDQLESTAHSRIRKERPISLGIFPLPAGDGLLTPDAQKGGETPGSEQWKFQELSQPRSHTSLKVSNSPEPQKAVEQEDELSDVSQGGSKATTPASTANSDVATIPTDTPLKEENEGFVKVTDAPNKSEISKHIEVQVAQETRNVSTGSAENEEKSEVQAIIESTPELDMDKDLSGYKGSSTPTKGIENKAFDRNTESLFEELSSAGSGLIGDVDEGADLLGMGREVENLILENTQLLETKNALNIVKNDLIAKVDELTCEKDVLQGELEAVKQAKLKLEEKNRELEEELRKARAEAEDARQKAKDDDDSDIPTAQRKRFTRVEMARVLMERNQYKERLMELQEAVRWTEMIRASRENPAMQEKKRSSIWQFFSRLFSSSSNTTKKPEPPVNLKYNAPTSHVTPSVK
```

the output will look like this

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
IQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQL
>sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
MQPILLLLAFLLLPRADAGEIIGGHEAKPHSRPYMAYLMIWDQKSLKRCGGFLIRDDFVLTAAHCWGSSINVTLGAHNIKEQEPTQQFIPVKRPIPHPAYNPKNFSNDIMLLQLERKAKRTRAVQPLRLPSNKAQVKPGQTCSVAGWGQTAPLGKHSHTLQEVKMTVQEDRKCES
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
IVVKGHSTCLSEGALSPDGTVLATASHDGYVKFWQIYIEGQDEPRCLHEWKPHDGRPLSCLLFCDNHKKQDPDVPFWRFLITGADQNRELKMWCTVSWTCLQTIRFSPDIFSSVSVPPSLKVCLDLSAEYLILSDVQRKVLYVMELLQNQEEGHACFSSISEFLLTHPVLSFGIQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQLNPDVVAPLPTHTAHEDFTFGESRPELGSEGLGSAAHGSQPDLRRIVELPAPADFLSLSSETKPKLMTPDAFMTPSASLQQITASPSSSSSGSSSSSSSSSSSLTAVSAMSSTSAVDPSLTRPPEELTLSPKLQLDGSLTMSSSGSLQASPRGLLPGLLPAPADKLTPKGPGQVPTATSALSLELQEVEP
```

I was trying to do it with bash like this

```
cat 1.txt | grep -A 2.txt | sed -n -e '1,/>/ {/>/ !' > myout.txt
```

Comment: Look at the option `-A` you have typed. What do you mean that to do? Did you mean `-f`?

Comment: @thb `A` Print num lines of trailing context after each match. You can see the option by `man grep`

Comment: @Learner, not sure if I get it, could you please do let us know what is logic behind getting this output?

Comment: try grep -v -f text.1 :) text.2

Comment: @thb I see that my regular expression is not good, it does not capture it

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have a bigger data and I have a smaller data, I am trying to remove those ones that I identified from bigger data.

Comment: so... you **could** say that you want to select/print the lines whose key value does not exist in 1.txt (as opposed to that you want to remove lines...).

Comment: again grep -v -f text.1 text.2 (this will use text1.txt as pattern file for the grep. -v will print lines that do NOT match. done.

Comment: @Ed Morton Yes, I am breaking down my problem and each step helps me learn something new

Comment: @Learner my point is you're still thinking about your requirements in terms of what to remove given some condition while the tools you're using are designed around the opposite logic - what to print given some condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} /^>/{f=($2 in a ? 0 : 1)} f' 1.txt 2.txt
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
IQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQL
>sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
MQPILLLLAFLLLPRADAGEIIGGHEAKPHSRPYMAYLMIWDQKSLKRCGGFLIRDDFVLTAAHCWGSSINVTLGAHNIKEQEPTQQFIPVKRPIPHPAYNPKNFSNDIMLLQLERKAKRTRAVQPLRLPSNKAQVKPGQTCSVAGWGQTAPLGKHSHTLQEVKMTVQEDRKCES
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
IVVKGHSTCLSEGALSPDGTVLATASHDGYVKFWQIYIEGQDEPRCLHEWKPHDGRPLSCLLFCDNHKKQDPDVPFWRFLITGADQNRELKMWCTVSWTCLQTIRFSPDIFSSVSVPPSLKVCLDLSAEYLILSDVQRKVLYVMELLQNQEEGHACFSSISEFLLTHPVLSFGIQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQLNPDVVAPLPTHTAHEDFTFGESRPELGSEGLGSAAHGSQPDLRRIVELPAPADFLSLSSETKPKLMTPDAFMTPSASLQQITASPSSSSSGSSSSSSSSSSSLTAVSAMSSTSAVDPSLTRPPEELTLSPKLQLDGSLTMSSSGSLQASPRGLLPGLLPAPADKLTPKGPGQVPTATSALSLELQEVEP
```

Comment: or `f=!($2 in a)`

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but went with what I have for the little bit of extra clarity IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to print lines whose 2nd column is NOT coming in 1.txt then try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} /^>/ {flag=$2 in a?1:0}flag' 1.txt FS="|" 2.txt
```

Above will print all the lines which are satisfying condition for `>` and coming after it, in case OP wants to print only 2 lines after `>` line then try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} /^>/ {flag=$2 in a?1:0;count=2} flag && count-->0' 1.txt FS="|" 2.txt
```

Comment: this is almost exact copy of @Ed Morton's answer.

Comment: @karakfa, yes please, I saw it after posting. Added 1 more solution(by seeing OP's attempt) in it now.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work (not tested), needs `gawk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next}
    !($2 in a) {print rt $0} {rt=RT}' file1 RS='(^|\n)>' FS='|' file2
```

Answer (score 1):

That was a bit tricky. Here you go.

```
grep -v -f <(sed -e 's/^\(.*\)$/\^>sp|\1|/' 1.txt) 2.txt | sed -ne '/^>/{p;n;p}'
```

The regular expressions (regex) are in the old (rather than revised/extended) POSIX style. The first regex, `/^\(.*\)$/`, matches each line of *1.txt* to change, for example, `P13674` to `^>sp|P13674|`. The last, as you see, matches the beginning of a line in *2.txt*. You could omit the first pattern, just typing `grep -v -f 1.txt 2.txt | sed ...`, and that would still practically probably work. I just thought it neater to match the beginning of a line more precisely.

The second regex, `/^>/`, distinguishes lines that begin with `>` from those that do not, because these two kinds of line want different handling.

By the way, I agree with you. The Awk solution is probably preferable. However, since you had started with Grep, my solution has followed in that vein.

Comment: thanks I liked your solution (how did you come up with the regular expression :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try Perl, check below

```
perl -ne ' BEGIN {@x=map{chomp;$_} qx(cat 1.txt);$pat=join("|",@x) } print if not /$pat/ '
```

with inputs

```
$ perl -ne ' BEGIN {@x=map{chomp;$_} qx(cat 1.txt);$pat=join("|",@x) } print if not /$pat/ ' 2.txt
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR
VECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDIIIVLDQKDHAVFTRRGEDLFMCMDIQLVEALCGFQKPISTLDNRTIVITSHPGQIVKHGDIKCVLNEGMPIYRRPYEKGRLIIEFKVNFPENGFLSPDKLSLLEKLLPERKEVEE
MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWVTQIATTPQFPDMILSASRDKTIIMWKLTRDETNYGIPQRALRGHSHFVSDVVISSDGQFALSGSWDGTLRLWDLTTGTTTRRFVGHTKDVLSVAFSSDNRQIVSGSRDKTIKLWNTLGVCKYTVQDESHSEWVSCVRFSPNSSNPIIVSCGWDKLVKVWNLANCKLK
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
IQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQL
>sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
MQPILLLLAFLLLPRADAGEIIGGHEAKPHSRPYMAYLMIWDQKSLKRCGGFLIRDDFVLTAAHCWGSSINVTLGAHNIKEQEPTQQFIPVKRPIPHPAYNPKNFSNDIMLLQLERKAKRTRAVQPLRLPSNKAQVKPGQTCSVAGWGQTAPLGKHSHTLQEVKMTVQEDRKCES
MGKDYYQTLGLARGASDEEIKRAYRRQALRYHPDKNKEPGAEEKFKEIAEAYDVLSDPRKREIFDRYGEEGLKGSGPSGGSGGGANGTSFSYTFHGDPHAMFAEFFGGRNPFDTFFGQRNGEEGMDIDDPFSGFPMGMGGFTNVNFGRSRSAQEPARKKQDPPVTHDLRVSLEEIYSGCTKKMKISHK
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
IVVKGHSTCLSEGALSPDGTVLATASHDGYVKFWQIYIEGQDEPRCLHEWKPHDGRPLSCLLFCDNHKKQDPDVPFWRFLITGADQNRELKMWCTVSWTCLQTIRFSPDIFSSVSVPPSLKVCLDLSAEYLILSDVQRKVLYVMELLQNQEEGHACFSSISEFLLTHPVLSFGIQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQLNPDVVAPLPTHTAHEDFTFGESRPELGSEGLGSAAHGSQPDLRRIVELPAPADFLSLSSETKPKLMTPDAFMTPSASLQQITASPSSSSSGSSSSSSSSSSSLTAVSAMSSTSAVDPSLTRPPEELTLSPKLQLDGSLTMSSSGSLQASPRGLLPGLLPAPADKLTPKGPGQVPTATSALSLELQEVEP
MIHNYMEHLERTKLHQLSGSDQLESTAHSRIRKERPISLGIFPLPAGDGLLTPDAQKGGETPGSEQWKFQELSQPRSHTSLKVSNSPEPQKAVEQEDELSDVSQGGSKATTPASTANSDVATIPTDTPLKEENEGFVKVTDAPNKSEISKHIEVQVAQETRNVSTGSAENEEKSEVQAIIESTPELDMDKDLSGYKGSSTPTKGIENKAFDRNTESLFEELSSAGSGLIGDVDEGADLLGMGREVENLILENTQLLETKNALNIVKNDLIAKVDELTCEKDVLQGELEAVKQAKLKLEEKNRELEEELRKARAEAEDARQKAKDDDDSDIPTAQRKRFTRVEMARVLMERNQYKERLMELQEAVRWTEMIRASRENPAMQEKKRSSIWQFFSRLFSSSSNTTKKPEPPVNLKYNAPTSHVTPSVK

$
```